# How to pass variable number of parameters to a shell command?

Tags: shell

I am writing a script for backup like this:

**backup.sh**:

```
dir="$1"
mode="$2"
delta="$3"

for file in "$dir/backup."*".$mode.tar.gz"; do
    [ "$file" -nt "$ref" ] && ref="$file"
done

if [ "$delta" = "true" ]; then
    delta_cmd=-N "'$ref'"
fi

backup_file="$dir/backup.$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).$mode.tar.gz"

case "$mode" in
    config)
        tar -cpzvf "$backup_file" $delta_cmd \
            /etc \
            /usr/local
            ;;
    # still other modes here...
esac
```

I want to pass a single variable `$delta_cmd` to the tar command so that it tars all files or only delta files since last backup depending on the value of `$delta`.

The above code creates an error message and does not tar the delta files correctly if `$delta` is set to true. How to fix it?

P.S: The script would better be POSIX compatible.

Comment: It's *possible* to make this POSIX compatible, but only by either introducing security vulnerabilities (using `eval`) or overwriting `$@` (which is quite *not* compatible with the use of a `delta_cmd` string) -- which would mean encapsulating the code in a function if you don't want to override the script-global value for that array. See BashFAQ #50 for a description of why string variables (as opposed to arrays) can't be safely used to store argument lists or commands, at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the overwriting `$@` way?

Comment: Added an answer. BTW, there's quite a lot in this code that could afford to be cut down to create a proper MCVE (**minimal**, complete, verifiable example; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- I'm very much hesitant to include content in my answer that includes such bad practices as parsing `ls`, but a better-practices replacement for that code is also somewhat outside the scope of the question at hand.

Comment: ...that said, please see BashFAQ #3 at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003 for guidance on a best-practices way to find the newest, or oldest, file in a directory. (We also have answers in the StackOverflow knowledge base about using GNU find to efficiently and -- unlike `ls` -- **robustly** find the most or least recent N files).

Comment: Thank you. I reduced the script in problem.

Comment: `$delta_cmd` is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a POSIX-compliant approach, consider:

```
set --                  # clear $@
if [ -f "$ref" ]; then
  set -- "$@" -N "$ref" # add -N "$ref" to $@
fi

tar ... "$@" ...        # expand $@ into command line
```

---

To put this all in context, and protect the main argument list against overwrite, might look like:

```
#!/bin/sh

main() {
    # if current shell supports "local", prevent variables from leaking
    # ...some "POSIX" shells, such as ash, will be fine with this.
    local dir mode delta target_file backup_file 2>&1 ||:

    dir=$1
    mode=$2
    delta=$3

    set -- # clear $@

    for file in "$dir/backup."*".$mode.tar.gz"; do
        [ "$file" -nt "$ref" ] && ref="$file"
    done

    if [ "$delta" = "true" ]; then
        set -- "$@" -N "$ref"
    fi

    target_file="$dir/backup.$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).$mode.tar.gz"

    case "$mode" in
        config)
            tar -cpzvf "$target_file" "$@" \
                /etc \
                /usr/local
            ;;
        # still other modes here...
    esac
}

main "$@"
```

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. If we put the code fragment to a function in sub-shell such as `backup () ( ... )` it would not overwrite $@ would it?

Comment: correct, it would only overwrite the `$@` for that function. You actually don't need `backup() ( ... )`, `backup() { ... }` would suffice, since a function is in a different stack frame and so has its own argument list.

Comment: Note that there had been an error in the original post which was corrected: `target_file` should be `backup_file`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using BASH arrays for storing partial/full command lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=/home/sysop/backup
mode=main
delta=false

REF=$(ls -t "$DIR"/system.*.$mode.tar.gz "$DIR"/system.*.$mode-delta.tar.gz 2>/dev/null | head -n 1)
REF=$(readlink -f "$REF")

if [ "$delta" = true ]; then
    delta_cmd=(-N "$REF")
    delta_suffix=("-delta")
fi

target_file="$DIR/system.$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).$mode$delta_suffix.tar.gz"

tar -cpzvf "$target_file" "${delta_cmd[@]}" \
    /etc \
    /usr/local \
    /var/log \
    /var/spool \
    /home/*/logs
```

I would also suggest avoiding parsing of `ls` command's output in your script.

Comment: It does not seem to work POSIX-ly due to syntax error. I also tried using bash, but the result is error as previously if $delta=true.

Comment: This script should run on BASH. Can you tell me what is exact error while using BASH?

Comment: My real script uses a different path for $DIR which could potentially contain a space. Here is the error: 
tar: Substituting -9223372036854775807 for unknown date format ‘'/path/to/subdir’
tar: after-space/system.20160802-004650.main-delta.tar.gz': Cannot stat: No such file or directory

Comment: Post edited to more match the real script I use. I think the question is this line: `+ tar -cpzvf '/path/to/subdir after-space/system.20160802-005757.config-delta.tar.gz' -N ''\''/path/to/subdir' 'after-space/system.20160802-005348.config-delta.tar.gz'\''' /etc /usr/local`

Comment: Oh you have misplaced quoted in array assignment. Note that I have `delta_cmd=(-N "$REF")` but you are showing `delta_cmd=(-N "'$ref'")`

Comment: I fixed it. Now it's still error: `+ tar -cpzvf '/path/to/subdir after-space/system.20160802-010819.config-delta.tar.gz' -N /path/to/subdir after-space/system.20160802-005757.config-delta.tar.gz /etc /usr/local`

Comment: I run the above command with `DIR='/path/to/subdir after-space'`. The above command causes error since it is parsed as `-N /path/to/subdir` and `after-space/system.20160802-005757.config-delta.tar.gz` separately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118840/discussion-between-anubhava-and-danny-lin).

Comment: You are not copying correctly from my answer. I have `"${delta_cmd[@]}"` but you have `$delta_cmd`.

Comment: You are right. After replacing `$delta_cmd` to `"${delta_cmd[@]}"`, it works now.

Comment: It needs BASH due to use of BASH arrays